# GPS location only returns null (0.0,0.0)

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have an application for Android devices, with multiple addresses. By clicking on any address, wanted to get the user's current location and play the link on google maps (http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr = "), along with the coordinates of the destination.

However, the results of "latitude" and "longitude" present only return "0.0".

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for bad english.

```
public class Guaruja extends Activity Activity implements LocationListener {

Button bttela2;
TextView t1;
Uri uri;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
String provider;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guaruja);

    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextView1);


    TextView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String lati = String.valueOf(latitude);
            String longi = String.valueOf(longitude);
            String firt = "http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr=";
            String secord="&daddr=-22.748085, -47.369444";
            String virgula=",";
            String url= firt+latitude+virgula+longitude+secord;
            uri=Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }


    });


}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location){

       latitude = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
       longitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;

    }

   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}


public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}


public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
```

Permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: well for one you never requested location updated from the location manager so you never get a location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of receiving location via programming, I did google work for me. If you leave the field "starting point" of the link in blank ("&saddr="), the coordinates will be the "current location".

The link on google maps must be like this: "http://maps.google.com/maps?&saddr=&daddr=-23.990624,-46.282269&sensor=TRUE".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article on the Android Developer's site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

As mentioned in the comment above, you need to actually request updates from the Location Service. Otherwise, you'll never get a callback.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You'll notice that the last argument is a LocationListener object. This is the object that handles the callbacks. I see that you have the "onLocationChanged" method, but your class doesn't implement the LocationListener interface, so that method won't do anything.

Additionally, the permission to access coarse location is redundant, since it's implied with the fine location permission.

Comment: I used the code like: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, LocationListener);      But not worked

Comment: Did you register your activity as a location listener? Your class delcaration should look something like this:

`public class Guaruja extends Activity implements LocationListener {`

Comment: Now I added. But not work for me. Latitude and Longitude aways return "null". :s

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that your GPS_PROVIDER isn't turned on, literally on your phone. I'm also assuming you're testing this on a phone and not an emulator.

Comment: I'm testing on a Samsung S3. Direct testing by Google Maps, the current location is displayed. This is not normal